# Is there a performance cost using std::move vs using a pointer to the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, memory

I imagine std::move() has a bit more of a performance cost in the context of something like:

```
std::thread thrd(&func, this);
someArrOfThreads[0] = std::move(thrd);
```

vs

```
std::thread *thrd = new std::thread(&func, this);
someArrOfThreadPointers[0] = thrd;
```

Is this true? And if so, is it a matter of `std::move()` changes the boundaries of memory of the thread or something else?

I realize there is the difference that in the first I am actually assigning a value of the array to the thread, and the other being the pointer to the thread, the thread stays in its address(es) in the second.

Comment: *"I imagine"* and performance of C++ code don't go well together. Measure everything.

Comment: There's also a cost of dereferencing a pointer, so it's not easy to say either way. Measure.

Comment: You forgot to `delete` the thread.

Comment: I'm not really asking in actuality, I'm more curious if there is a theoretical better way due to how the thread is being move vs dereferenced.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, yes I did :), these are just example snip-its

Comment: Then your question is just opinion-based, isn't it?

Comment: My complete and utter guess would be that the two are essentially the same. In order for thread objects to be *movable* they could well simply be wrappers round a pointer to something thready.

Comment: @Brian there's a difference between theoretical and opinion, I'm asking if std::move is actually moving the thread in memory, and therefore, more costly than getting a pointer to the thread.

Comment: Moving the entire thread, as in taking the entire virtual address space the thread occupies, and moving it to another address? Of course it doesn't do that. `std::thread` is probably just a wrapper around `pthread_t`.

Comment: @Brian ok, these are the things I'm asking about.

Comment: Looking at the `GCC` implementation on `Linux` it apparently contains nothing more than a native handle (`unsigned long int`) so the `std::move` version should, if anything, be faster than using pointers.

Comment: @Galik can you elaborate on why that is? Maybe as an answer?

Comment: @ChristianGrabowski Its very implementation specific and this is my first time looking through the `std::thread` source code so I don't feel I have enough of a handle on it to give an authoritative answer. There are still things happening in their I have not figured out yet.

Comment: Well, if you're asking about comparing performance of two code samples, neither of them should be buggy. It doesn't do for one of them to have a memory leak.

Comment: @juanchopanza that's not the point of what I am asking, I am asking from a theoretical standpoint, is there one that is more costly.

Comment: And what is the point of comparing the performance of code without a bug vs code with a bug?

Comment: @juanchopanza because this isn't actual code *it's a snip-it* to specify what I'm asking, yes there would be a bug, except this isn't actual code being used anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only thing that `std::move` does is turn a lvalue into an rvalue reference. This then causes the rvalue reference version of the assignment operator to be called. From a code generation point of view it is a noop.

The rvalue overload is likely to be more efficient since it is allowed to move class internal as opposed to performing a deep copy.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `std::thread` can't be copied, so to compare rvalue assignment to "deep copy" assignment isn't meaningful as the latter doesn't even exist.

Comment: My answer is about the more general usage of std::move. Not specifically about the OP's question

Answer (score 3):

How threads are implemented is very platform specific. However classes that implement *move semantics* typically hold only a *handle* for or *pointer* to the actual objects they manage.

For that reason the `std::move` is likely to be doing something similar to your pointer example on the inside. You can generally expect *moving* objects to be efficient.

Looking at how `std::thread` is implemented in `GCC` on `Linux` it apparently contains one data item a solitary `unsigned long int` which is the handle to a thread using the `<pthreads>` library.

When you do `someArrOfThreads[0] = std::move(thrd);` it simply swaps the thread's handle with the one in the array.

That should be pretty fast and you don't have the constant overhead of using *indirection* that you would have if you were using pointers.

Even though implementations may differ the `std::move` version using *values* rather than the *pointer* has to be preferred.

Typically *move semantics* are as fast as (and possibly faster than) using pointers but also they are generally safer and less fiddly.

Comment: The big advantage of move is that it is only done once. Pointers add another layer of indirection that has to be traverse every time an object in the array is accessed and since the underlying objects are unlikely to be contiguous, is more likely to incur a cache-miss penalty

Answer (score 1):

`new` will be slower because it uses the heap. Storing instance(s) of `std::thread` in an object will be able to take advantage of the time spent in the allocation of its container, which may have also been near zero cost because it might be a local variable or have static lifetime.

Also, `new` will have poorer locality than a member variable or local variable, the instance could end up anywhere in memory. Accessing the heap might require a lock to be acquired, severely reducing performance.

Don't downgrade to C style code because you think you will save nanoseconds. You won't.